# Will native events interrupt React fiber updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

I know that events bound to dom in React will eventually be React's synthetic events, but if I use the following method

`const dom = document.querySelector(xx); dom.addEventListener('click', () => { //do something });`
So when I click, will the click event interrupt the React update? If so, how does the fiber know it needs to be interrupted?

Understand the inner workings

Comment: useRef, fibre adds a some dynamic id to the end of things and document.query* should be avoided in React in favour of useRef which will keep track of your element between renders https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef